# seaborn lmplot - weird automatic choice of axis limits

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a dataset with coordinates and two categorical variables.
I am trying to plot it using `lmplot` using `C1` as `hue` and `C2` as `col`.

```
sns.lmplot(x='x',y='y',hue='C1',col='C2',col_wrap=2,data=df,ci=None)
```

Sample dataset:

```
    C1   C2    y          x
    B1   L1    4.043633   0.040000
    B2   L1    3.756300   0.070000
    B2   L2    1.485845   0.004537
    B3   L3    4.481500   0.000690
    B4   L2    17.427691  0.044007
    B2   L3    4.065942   0.007542
    B1   L3    4.043633   0.046660
    B3   L1    3.756300   0.074520
    B4   L1    1.485845   0.006737
    B2   L4    4.481500   0.001090
    B3   L4    17.427691  0.605507
    B4   L4    4.065942   0.007722
    B4   L3    3.068882   0.009922
    B3   L2    13.06802   0.408822
    B1   L2    4.481500   0.001090
    B1   L4    18.876591  0.056507
```

The max and min of the coordinates are:

```
max:
y                22.712
x                 0.625

min:
y                 0
x                 0.003
```

However, some of the fitted lines have a crazy wide support:

[image]

How do I force `seaborn` to stick to "normal" axis limits?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to force `lmplot` to do that (currently). The problem is that for each line the current limits are taken, and then the axis is autoscaled, such that the limits for the next line are wider. For many lines this adds up to an undesireable "zoom-out". You can set the limits manually though.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest so it's the repeated plotting of lines that causes problems, not a specific line of the group? Do you think I should report it as an issue? (if it doesn't exist already) I will then just pick the max and min of each axis and manually set it myself, thanks.